# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, json.net, json-deserialization

How to properly deserialize POST method "Update" while developing Telegram bot in ASP.NET Core Web API by using Telegram.Bot package?
I used DeserializeObject(string) method to do so, but it keeps returning the error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace OfficeBooking.TelegramApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route(template: "api/message")]
    public class TelegramBotController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly TelegramBotClient _telegramBotClient;

        public TelegramBotController(TelegramBot telegramBot)
        {
            _telegramBotClient = telegramBot.GetBot().Result;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task <IActionResult> Update([FromBody]object update)
        {
            var upd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Update>(update.ToString());
            var chat = upd.Message?.Chat;

            if (chat == null)
            {
                return Ok();
            }

            await _telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: chat.Id,
                    text: "Testing sendMessage method",
                    parseMode: ParseMode.MarkdownV2,
                    disableNotification: false,
                    replyMarkup: new InlineKeyboardMarkup(
                        InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl(
                            "Check sendMessage method",
                            "https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage")));

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged through the code to find out what the value of `update.ToString()` is? Is there any reason you don't just have the parameter declared as `[FromBody] Update upd` (rather then deserializing it in the method body)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to lean on ASP.NET Core to parse your json input. You can simply specify type **Update** instead of **object** and it will do the rest for you. You just need to use ready object with type **Update**:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task <IActionResult> Update([FromBody]Update update)
        {
            var chat = update.Message?.Chat;

            if (chat == null)
            {
                return Ok();
            }

            await _telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: chat.Id,
                    text: "Testing sendMessage method",
                    parseMode: ParseMode.MarkdownV2,
                    disableNotification: false,
                    replyMarkup: new InlineKeyboardMarkup(
                        InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl(
                            "Check sendMessage method",
                            "https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage")));

            return Ok();
        }
```

If you want framework to use NewtonsoftJson instead of default Json Utility (which is not necessary in your case), please follow this instructions https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/